# Intuition behind last==i?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am solving a question on [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-labels/):

> A string S of lowercase letters is given. We want to partition this string into as many parts as possible so that each letter appears in at most one part, and return a list of integers representing the size of these parts.
>
> Example: 
> Input: S = "ababcbacadefegdehijhklij"
> Output: [9,7,8]
> Explanation:
> The partition is "ababcbaca", "defegde", "hijhklij".
> This is a partition so that each letter appears in at most one part.
> A partition like "ababcbacadefegde", "hijhklij" is incorrect, because it splits S into less parts.

One of the [highly upvoted solutions](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-labels/discuss/113259/Java-2-pass-O(n)-time-O(1)-space-extending-end-pointer-solution) is as follows:

```
public List<Integer> partitionLabels(String S) {
        if(S == null || S.length() == 0){
            return null;
        }

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] map = new int[26];  // record the last index of the each char

        for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
            map[S.charAt(i)-'a'] = i;
        }
        
        // record the end index of the current sub string
        int last = 0;
        int start = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
            last = Math.max(last, map[S.charAt(i)-'a']);
            if(last == i){
                list.add(last - start + 1);
                start = last + 1;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

While I do understand the solution, I am not very comfortable with the statement `last = Math.max(last, map[S.charAt(i)-'a']);` and the clause `if(last == i)`.  What exactly is being done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to understand what exactly this `for` loop is doing, you have to understand the way that `map` is setup. It uses this loop to populate it:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
    map[S.charAt(i)-'a'] = i;
}
```

Now, this took me a second as well, but bear with me. What it is doing is looping through every character of `S`. Simple enough. Now, it is then getting the index to put `i` into the array: `S.charAt(i)-'a'`. This is some very clever programming. What it is doing is getting the character at the current position. For example, if we were at index `1` in the string, `S.charAt(i)` would be `'b'`. We then subtract `'a'` from that, which converts them into their UTF-16 character codes and subtracts them from one another. This would place them at position `1` in the array. It then sets that index equal to `i`. So at index 1 in the string, element 1 of the array equal to 1. A little bit more confusing, but let's keep going. If we are at index 5 of the string, we have the last occurrence of `'b'`. Since `'b'-'a'` is still 1, it will override the array at index 1, but since `i` has changed, so has the value there. Since that was the last index, we can know the last index of every character in the array.

Now that we have the array population out of the way, let's get to your actual question. In the next loop, it is going through the array just like it did the first time, but this time it knows the last index of all of the characters. So when we run the statement, `last = Math.max(last, map[S.charAt(i)-'a']);`, what it is doing is getting the last index of the current character from the array, using the same method as described before. It is then comparing that to the current `last` value. Why this is special is because that value is persistent. So, it gets that last index of `'a'`, and it gets the last index of `'b'`, and gets the bigger of the two. This is what actually puts them in their sections. So, now that we have `last` as the last index of the current section, we can compare that to the actual current index. If they are equal, we are at the end of the section, and can add that to the list.

I hope this all makes since, and don't hesitate to ask any questions!

**EDIT:**
Let's look at an example. Say we have the string: `ababcbacadefegdehijhklij`. If we run the first loop that populates the `map` array, it will look something like this:

```
+----------------+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Index          | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
+----------------+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Value          | 8 | 5 | 7 | 14 | 15 | 11 | 13 | 19 | 22 | 23 | 20 | 21 |
+----------------+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Character      | a | b | c | d  | e  | f  | g  | h  | i  | j  | k  | l  |
| representation |   |   |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
+----------------+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

(Note: the character representation is just for reference on which indices are which)

When we start the second for loop, we get the character in the string at 0, being `'a'`. We then check the `map` to see where the last index of it is, which is 8. Since the current index is 0 and not 8, we go to the next one. The next character, being `'b'`, has a value of 5 in `map`. We get the max between the previous value of `last`, which was 8, and 5, to get the last index for those two characters combined.

Let's skip to position 8. By this time we have seen `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. The largest of all of their last indices was `'a'`'s, being 8. Since we are at position 8, and the value of `last` is 8, we can say that the characters between `start` and `last` are a group, add it to the list, and set the value of `start` to the index of `last+1`. This is to setup the correct start position for the next group.

Now, if we move to the next index, index 9, we have a new character that we've never seen before. We simply start the process over, as if we were at position 1. Index 9 is `'d'`, which has a last index of 14. Since we're not at index 14, we go on to the next one. At index 10, we have `'e'`. This one has a last index of 15, which is bigger than `'d'`'s 14, so we take 15 because it is bigger. That just basically means that if `'d'` and `'e'` were in a group, it will at least have to go all the way to index 15, in order to encapsulate all of the characters for both of them. It then runs through the rest of them, updating `last`, until it gets to the end, where it cuts it off as a group.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please elaborate "_This is what actually puts them in their sections_"?  How does calculating the higher of the `last`s put them into their sections?  Better yet, _what_ is creating a section in the first place?

Comment: @J.Doe I just updated the answer to give more information with an example.

Comment: I got your point.  Thanks for the explanation.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Umm, actually, `charAt` returns the UTF-16 code unit at a position in the string. (And, there is no need to limit map to 26 elements. Character.MAX_VALUE + 1 would be simpler.)

Comment: It's true that Java characters are UTF-16 encoded. That's my bad, but there is a very specific reason that `map` should be 26 elements. Since you subtract a specific letters' integer value from `'a'`, you get its value relative to 0x0 rather than 0x60. This means that a-z will only range 0-26.

Answer (score 0):

Put in words, the solution goes as follows: starting from the beginning of the string, let's iteratively keep finding the shortest substring that satisfies the condition of the statement (i.e., for every letter in this substring, all of its occurrences belong to this substring). This is an application of the so-called greedy algorithm and it's relatively intuitive why it's correct: the shorter the substrings we take, the more of them there'll be, and we already established we are taking the shortest substrings humanly possible. The specific lines that you are questioning do the following:

`last = Math.max(last, map[S.charAt(i)-'a'])` - we are computing, of all the characters in the current substring, which character occurs as far as possible to the right

`if(last == i){` - we are checking whether, of all the characters in the current substring, the one that occurs as far to the right as possible is the one we are currently looking at - which would mean that the substring can end right here

Let's go over an example of how this approach would work. Let's try to partition the string `abacdbzz`. We construct this helper array `map` that looks like `{2, 5, 3, 4, 0, ..., 0, 7}`.

i=0: We start from the left of the string and look at character `a`. If there were no more `a`'s in the string, we could finish our first substring right here and start a new one from the next character. Unfortunately, there are more `a`'s in the string, which we realize by updating `last` to `map['a'-'a']=2`.

i=1: We are looking at `b` and realize that there are `b`'s even further than our current `last`, i.e, between `a`'s and `b`'s, the last `b` occurs further to the right. We reflect this observation by updating `last` to `map['b'-'a']=5`.

i=2: We encounter an `a` again, and it's the last `a` in the string, but we cannot end our substring here because we know that there is something (`b`) within our substring that still has occurrences outside it.

i=3, 4: We encounter a `c` and a `d`, which change nothing in our state because they don't have any other occurrences. `last` is still 5.

i=5: We finally found our last `b`. At this point, the condition `last == i` is satisfied; in other words, there are no occurrences of the letters within our substring (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) left to the right. This is the shortest possible substring we could take, and we proudly add it to the partition and start the new substring at the next position.

i=6: We encounter a `z` and update `last` with its rightmost occurrence's index `map['z'-'a']=7`.

i=7: The second `z` is found, and `last == i` is satisfied (for the last character in the string, this will always be true), so we add this string to the partition.

The end.